# Extracting contents with XML tags using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have few xml(s) as below. I want to extract the contents (as dataframe) from the xml(s) as per the below expected output using Beautiful Soup in Python. Kindly help me out.

**Sample XML :**

```
<Author AffiliationIDS="Aff1 Aff2" CorrespondingAffiliationID="Aff1" ORCID="http://orcid.org/0000-0003-4649-327X">
    <AuthorName DisplayOrder="Western">
        <GivenName>Anouk</GivenName>
        <GivenName>van der</GivenName>
        <FamilyName>Hoorn</FamilyName>
    </AuthorName>
    <Contact>
        <Phone>+31-50-3612400</Phone>
        <Fax>+31-50-3611707</Fax>
        <Email>a.van.der.hoorn@umcg.nl</Email>
    </Contact>
</Author>
<Author AffiliationIDS="Aff1">
 <AuthorName DisplayOrder="Western">
    <GivenName>Kamal</GivenName>
    <GivenName>M.</GivenName>
    <FamilyName>Aden</FamilyName>
 </AuthorName>
</Author>
<Author AffiliationIDS="Aff1 Aff2">
 <AuthorName DisplayOrder="Western">
    <GivenName>Peter</GivenName>
    <GivenName>Jan</GivenName>
    <FamilyName>van Laar</FamilyName>
 </AuthorName>
</Author>
```

**Expected Output :**

```
Anouk van der Hoorn         AuthorName
Kamal M. Aden               AuthorName
Peter Jan var Laar          AuthorName
```

Comment: Kindly help us out by posting the code that you have tried and identifying the problems that you have.

Answer (score 1):

here is the code, just in a few lines :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b
with open("sample.xml", "r") as f: # opening xml file
    content = f.read()
soup = b(content, "lxml")
authornames = ([values.find("authorname").text.replace("\n", ' ') for values in soup.findAll("author")])
print authornames
```

Output:

```
[u' Anouk van der Hoorn ', u' Kamal M. Aden ', u' Peter Jan van Laar ']
```